# Where to place Bootstrap CDN in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

so I am trying to avoid installing bootstrap in my MEAN project via npm and just want to use the bootstrap CDN. I have placed it in the angularjs public dist/public index.html file. This is where the root-component rests.The public folder is the angularjs. When placed there, it works. However, after refreshing the browser it does not work because the CDN completely disappears from that file. Perhaps I'm not allowed to make changes to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Shoot I was in the wrong folder. I used the src/app index.html to place the bootstrap CDN.